# Calling overridden function from the overriding function

Tags: c++, inheritance, oop, virtual, overriding

Suppose I have virtual function foo() in class B, and I need slightly different behavior in one of B's derived classes, class D. Is it OK to create an overriding function D::foo(), and call B::foo() from there, after the special case treatment? Like this:

```
void D::foo()
{
  if (/*something*/)
     // do something
  else
     B::foo();
}
```

I am not asking whether that would work, I know it will. I want to know, whether it is right in terms of a good OOD.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is perfectly good.  In fact, the canonical way of performing some operations is calling the base class method, then do whatever (or the other way around).  I am thinking of `operator=` here.  Constructors usually work that way, too, even if this is a bit disguised in the initialization list.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, its totally ok as long as you are not violating the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is.

Comment: Common, standard, normal, typical, widely-used.  Indeed, it's absolutely essential to be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen GUI frameworks use this to fall back on the base class's default implementation which contained code to signal errors/throw an exception/return a generic value.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok. Syntax you had gave can be also used to temporary turn off polymorphism, i.e. when you call obj->B::foo() method will be chosen from class B regardless if foo() is virtual or not and if obj is instance of B or not (it must be an instance of class extending B though).

Comment: You can't guarantee the function isn't called from a subclass of _B_, in which case you're not turning of anything at all.

Comment: @xtofl: You say that if I have B extends A, C extends B, i.e. A<B<C class hierarchy, and C obj;, then calling obj->B::foo() is permitted to call A::foo() ?

Comment: @xtolf: I just verified my answer and it appears to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is , that's what your compiler do for you every time it generates a constructor and a destructor: calling the mother's one for instance. I often rely on that"trick" in my own code.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to call base's implementation, but doing it **conditionally** moves you apart from constructor semantic, contrary to what have been suggested in other answers.

You may run into [fragile base class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) issue in two ways :

- By assuming `B::foo()` provides common behavior for the whole hierarchy (ie, forgetting the method isn't always called)
- Nasty problems depending on what `// do something` actually does !

For completeness, let's mention a symmetric design approach : [Template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_pattern) (base implementation calling specific sub-part)